# Reading genotype aloud

Tags: genetics, terminology

For this genotype, P2ry12$^{+/+}$ I read it "P2ry12 wild type." For animals with the GFP being expressed under one Cx3cr1 promoter, Cx3cr1$^{+/GFP}$, how do I read that aloud?

What about for: Cnr1$^{flox/flox}$, Cnr1$^{flox/+}$, Cx3cr1$^{CreER/CreER}$, and Cx3cr1$^{CreER/+}$ mice?

I'll give my attempts below and take suggestions:

Cx3cr1$^{+/GFP}$ "Cx3cr1 wild type with heterozygous GFP expression" or "Hetero GFP expression" or "GFP" as in for P2ry12$^{+/+}$, Cx3cr1$^{+/GFP}$ animals it would read "P2ry12 wild type with GFP" to reduce redundancy if it is clear to the listener.

Cnr1$^{flox/flox}$  "with Floxed Cnr1"

Cnr1$^{flox/+}$ "with hetero floxed Cnr1" Would the words incomplete or partial ever be appropriate here? As in "a partially floxed Cnr1?"

Cx3cr1$^{CreER/CreER}$ "homo CreER under the Cx3cr1CreER promoter" or just "the CreER animals"

Cx3cr1$^{CreER/+}$ "the hetero CreER animals"

and for CreER is it correct to say that is a chimeric protein of Cre and mutated hormone-binding domain of the estrogen receptor?

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
I do see that one of them is clarified by the authors: P2Y12-deficient (P2ry12$^{–/–)}$ GFP-expressing mice.

Comment: For something like this, just try your best to describe what it is. I don't think there's a definitive way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Cx3cr1 +/GFP +/+:

- "Cx3cr1 heterozygous with GFP expression" is the most accurate.
- "Hetero GFP expression" works if it's clear you're referring to
  Cx3cr1.

Cnr1 flox/flox +/- +/-:

- "Cnr1 floxed" or "homozygous for floxed Cnr1" are both good.

Cnr1 flox/+ +/- :

- "Cnr1 heterozygous floxed" works well.

Cx3cr1 CreER/CreER +/+ +/+:

- "Cx3cr1 CreER homozygous" is cleanest.

Cx3cr1 CreER/+ +/- :

- "Cx3cr1 CreER heterozygous" is perfect.

CreER is a chimeric protein combining Cre recombinase with a mutated estrogen receptor domain. This makes it activatable by tamoxifen administration.

Comment: Can you please explain the notation you used in these? For example: the "+/- +/-" in "Cnr1 flox/flox +/- +/-."

Comment: Thank you for your answer by the way! It was very helpful. I am reading them now from left to right and adding heterozygous or homozygous on the end accordingly.